# MOCK_LOCATION_PERMISSION Programmatically

Tags: android

I've provide MOCK_LOCATION_PERMISSION in Manifest file. Can we enable or disable the mock location access in android programmatically rather to go in Developer Options manually or by Settings.ACTION_APPLICATION_DEVELOPMENT_SETTINGS programmatically.

Comment: I sure hope not.

Comment: @CommonsWare Even if host is rooted?

Comment: @SamusArin: In that situation, sure. And, most likely, given root, there is some way to accomplish the OP's aim.